# vagrant up ubuntu-precise-64 notice git:command not found

Tags: git, vagrant

on Booting step ,it notice:

```
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default:
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default:
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if its present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
```

and can't use git.

Can use vagrant ssh,but have no git & curl

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear. Are you trying to use git once ssh'ed into vagrant or does git command fail even outside of vagrant? for the former case you might need to install git in the vagrant image (by sshing into it and then running `sudo apt-get install git`). In the latter case you might need to generate a key. Follow this tutorial
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/